# gzipping my site doesn't seem to work using htaccess - no Content-Encoding: gzip

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate

I'm trying to gzip my site. But I'm not sure if it's actually working..
When I'm checking at checkgzipcompression.com, WhatsMyIP.org and YSlow - they all tell me that the site is not compressed. Yslow also tells me that I have a couple of files that is not compressed, and of course suggest I do so.

This is the part, in my `htaccess`-file, that should compress the site:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
#   Force compression for mangled headers.
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
#   Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType  DEFLATE  application/atom+xml \
                                        application/javascript \
                                        application/json \
                                        application/rss+xml \
                                        application/vnd.ms-fontobject \
                                        application/x-font-ttf \
                                        application/x-web-app-manifest+json \
                                        application/x-httpd-php \
                                        application/x-httpd-fastphp \
                                        application/xhtml+xml \
                                        application/xml \
                                        font/opentype \
                                        image/svg+xml \
                                        image/x-icon \
                                        text/css \
                                        text/html \
                                        text/plain \
                                        text/x-component \
                                        text/xml
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

*This code is based on h5bp (https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.3.0/doc/TOC.md).*

If I add `ini_set("zlib.output_compression", 4096);` to the PHP initiation script - both checkgzipcompression.com and WhatsMyIP.org tells me that my site is compressed. Along with the page weight in kb.

But YSlow still tells me that I have multiple files that is not compressed.
And in developer tools for both chrome and firefox shows the uncompressed filesize for each request/file (I'm not sure if that's how it suppose to be though(?)).
It does say `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate`, and `Vary: Accept-Encoding`, but nothing like `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

I just had a chat with my server provider -- BlueHost -- and they said that `mod_deflate` runs automatically on all of their servers. But since it's dynamic, most website scanners don't see it.

The conclution was that it's not possible for me to actually be sure that my site is in fact compressed.

The `.htaccess`-file is as it's shown above, and `zlib.output_compression()` is turned off - in case you have the ability to check it out..

The domain is: http://barkeeper.thomaskile.me

Here's a acreenprint of what firefox has to say about the page:
[image: firefox dev tools]

Answer (score -1):

Same issue with Bluehost. I checked the actual file sizes and they are not compressed. Got the same BS that it automatic. First they tried telling me it only worked when the server was under a heavy load... apparently that person was clueless. Then I was told the server load threshold was low, and that compression was disabled when that threshold was exceeded. I am quite upset with these answers being all over the place.

Comment: And how exactyly that is an answer? It looks like a comment since it does not provide any solution or possible causes to the problem.